# ajaxToolkit:ComboBox Drop Down List

Tags: vb.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I my Web page I have a ComboBox Control

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="Country" runat="server" TabIndex="8" Width="145" 
                        BackColor="Silver" CssClass="RegComboCountryEntry"
                        ValidationGroup="SetUserValGroup" ToolTip="Country Selection"  />
```

And in my code behind I have the following code in order to load the Items.

```
CtryID.Clear()
CtryName.Clear()
            dbHandler.SQLComm = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM aspnet_UsersCountries", aspProvider.SQLConn)
            If aspProvider.SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then aspProvider.SQLConn.Open()
            myReader = dbHandler.SQLComm.ExecuteReader()
            While myReader.Read()
                Country.Items.Add(Trim(myReader(1)))
                CtryID.Add(myReader(0))
            End While
```

The all work is going fine, but the drop down list is not appeared in the proper position (just down of the control). instead it appears at the right - down position of the page.
And the Long of the list is not controlled. It has a standard Long.

Is it possible for someone to assist me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I solved my issue.
In the control I was use

```
asp:ComboBox
```

Instead of

```
<asp:DropDownList
```